# How to send push notifications to a Blazor Maui application from backend Server

Tags: c#, push-notification, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I have a Blazor Maui application where I'd like to have the option to receive push notifications on.
I'd like to send the push notifications from a server project inside the same solution where I have my Blazor Maui project. For example : the server should contain a Gui with a textbox for the title and messagebody. This should then sent to all the users who downloaded the app.

Any tutorials,links, examples, tips or recommendations on how to start this?

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBbbctEvbOk) guide before but this is all configured inside the app itself.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would recommend this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDr0Hx67guk. To be honest, there is no much difference in connecting to SignalR from MAUI, than any other .NET application. (Just keep an eye, what is run on main thread, and what not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .NET MAUI Blazor app is still a .NET MAUI app.

If you want to use push notifications, you're going to have to be on the platform level. The guide you linked might still be very useful for that.

The comment from @H.A.H. is a good option too, using SignalR, but that will only work if you're inside of the app. SignalR is not integrated into the OS like push notifications are. You are not able to get a banner in the top of the screen for instance. But definitely thanks for watching and recommending my videos ;)

If you want the "regular" push notifications, you can follow any guide that adds push notifications in a .NET MAUI app and that will work for .NET MAUI Blazor.

Comment: Please provide a link to documentation on integrating .NET MAUI with push notifications. I found this Xamarin example on Microsoft Learn (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm), which I got to work after correcting it. The NuGet packages are in .NET 4.61, and apparently will not work with .NET MAUI.

Answer (score -1):

you can use signalr for this purpose you can go throug following link

[click here](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=688d1682c1e8c984JmltdHM9MTY2ODAzODQwMCZpZ3VpZD0wYjI4ZmIzMy00NTBiLTZmMjYtMWRhZi1lYWM1NDEwYjYxZGEmaW5zaWQ9NTE3Mw&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=0b28fb33-450b-6f26-1daf-eac5410b61da&psq=signalr%20implementation%20with%20blazor&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9sZWFybi5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL2VuLXVzL2FzcG5ldC9jb3JlL2JsYXpvci90dXRvcmlhbHMvc2lnbmFsci1ibGF6b3I_dmlldz1hc3BuZXRjb3JlLTYuMA&ntb=1)